# How to edit a drupal theme before making an archive?

Tags: php, drupal, content-management-system

I'm having a problem with Drupal. I'm trying to create a new theme. The only problem is:

1, Drupal doesn't seem to let you view themes stored in Drupal by simply entering localhost/folder/[filename here] in your browser URL bar. It seems like you get the "page forbidden" message if you try to run any .php file in the drupal folder before turning it into a tar.gz file.

2, But once you make something into a tar.gz folder it's way harder to edit.

Do you simply need to create your drupal themes in a separate folder beforehand, compress them, and only THEN add them to drupal/sites/all/themes?

I get the page forbidden message whenever I try to run anything in the drupal folder but not directly through drupal...

Answer (score 0):

you can make the theme yourself by following a tutorial like this one:

http://tips.webdesign10.com/how-to-make-a-drupal-theme

you can effectively make the theme yourself on your own local instance without having to use a tar.gz file and then you can either ftp the files to the server you're running it on, or you can tar it up and upload the tar through the themes settings interface (Drupal 7+)

Hope that helps!